# API Analytics : Get primitiveValue from Multi-Channel Funnels response

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-api, google-api-php-client

I have an issue with Multi-Channel Funnels requests.

The JSON response is not the same that with classic request with ga: dimensions and metrics.
It returns  primitive values in rows and I can't get them.

Exemple :
Here is a classic request with metric ga:transactionRevenue, and dimension ga:transactionId.
I get this in rows :

```
"rows": [
  [
   "10292",
   "-231.5"
  ],
  [
   "11330",
   "0.0"
  ],
  [
   "12180",
   "37.5"
  ],
(...)
```

Easy to retrieve.

Now with metric mcf:firstInteractionValue and dimension mcf:sourceMedium.

```
 "rows": [
  [
   {
    "primitiveValue": "(direct) / (none)"
   },
   {
    "primitiveValue": "2066.2514"
   }
  ],
  [
   {
    "primitiveValue": "YH-TW / cpc"
   },
   {
    "primitiveValue": "0.0"
   }
   ],
   [
   {
    "primitiveValue": "ameblo.jp / referral"
   },
   {
    "primitiveValue": "0.0"
   }
  ],
(...)
```

I tried the getRows() method, but it returns me a weird array.
I also tried getPrimitiveValue() on MCFDataRows, but it return a null value.

```
$dataRows = $dataMCF->getRows();
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($dataRows); $i++){
     echo $dataRows[$i]->getPrimitiveValue();
}
```

result: *nothing*

Can you please help me to get those values ? :3

**Edit :**

The object $dataRows[0]

```
Google_Service_Analytics_McfDataRows Object
(
    [conversionPathValueType:protected] => Google_Service_Analytics_McfDataRowsConversionPathValue
    [conversionPathValueDataType:protected] => array
    [primitiveValue] => 
    [collection_key:protected] => items
    [modelData:protected] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
        (
            [primitiveValue] => (direct) / (none)
        )

        [1] => Array
        (
            [primitiveValue] => 2066.2514
        )

    )

    [processed:protected] => Array
    (
    )

)
```

I have the impression it is really simple, but i have been unable to get those values since this morning.
I don't see how to get the modelData:protected array. I read the entire MCF classes of the API 3 times, without finding the right function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this:

```
$dataRows = $dataMCF->getRows();
foreach($dataRows AS $row){
                $temp_row = array(  );
                foreach ((array)$row->toSimpleObject() as $key => $value) {
                    $temp_row[ $key ] = $value['primitiveValue'];
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally modified Analytics.php since google is not able to provide data properly.

I added this in class Google_Service_Analytics_McfDataRows:

```
public function getData(){
  return $this->modelData;
}
```